# box with content which slides below it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a grid in which I will have separate boxes. On clicking on these, boxes, I will show a `div` which will have data related to that box. I am using `jquery`'s `slideToggle` to show the `div`.

The whole setup works fine and I am happy with it. The first `row` contains the boxes and on clicking on each box, the content is shown below like below :

[image]

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.info-content-box').hide();

    var openedId = '';

    $('.info-box .info-header').click(function(e) {
        var id = '#' + $(this).data('name');

        if (openedId ==='') {
            $(id).slideToggle(400, function() {
                openedId = id;
            });
        } else {

            if (openedId == id) {
                $(openedId).slideToggle(400, null);
            } else {
                $(openedId).hide(10);
                $(id).fadeToggle(400, function() {
                    openedId = id;
                });
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.info-box {
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
}

.info-box .info-header {
    background-color: #3178b9;
    height: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #f5f0e7;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.info-box .info-header:hover {
    background-color: #b4a28f;
    border: 5px solid #f5f0e7;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}

.info-box .info-header .info-line {
 float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.info-box .info-header:hover .info-line {
 float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    width: 30%;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}

.info-content-box {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:50px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content1">
            <div class="info-line"></div>
            <p>hello</p>
            <div class="info-line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content2">
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content3">
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content4">
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="info-content-box" id="content1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content1" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-content-box" style="text-align: right" id="content2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content2" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-content-box" id="content3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content3" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-content-box" style="text-align: right" id="content4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content4" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However, I want my code snippet to be `responsive`, ie, I want that box to show right below the box in responsive mode. But since I have placed the content `div` in a `row` below the boxes `row`, the content shows in the end of all the boxes.

Please help me how to achieve this.

You can find my code at `Plunkr` - https://plnkr.co/edit/OiIjS2AmNKeqS1YqPph4

Basically what I want to achieve is here - http://www.tri-north.com/Home/Projects?filterCategory=&r=0

Here the content opens pushing all the other boxes below. It also works great in responsive mode.

**EDIT:**

I combined **StefanBob**'s answer and have modified my js to the below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.info-content-box').hide();

    var openedId = '';

    $('.info-box .info-header').click(function(e) {
        var id = '#' + $(this).data('name');

        if (openedId === '') {
            if ($(window).width() < 992) {
                $(id).insertAfter($(this).parent());
                $(id).slideToggle(400, function() {
                    openedId = id;
                });
            } else {
                $(id).slideToggle(400, function() {
                    openedId = id;
                });
            }
        } else {

            if (openedId == id) {
                if ($(window).width() < 992) {
                    $(id).insertAfter($(this).parent());
                    $(openedId).slideToggle(400, null);
                } else {
                    $(openedId).slideToggle(400, null);
                }
            } else {
                $(openedId).hide(10);
                if ($(window).width() < 992) {
                    $(id).insertAfter($(this).parent());
                    $(id).fadeToggle(400, function() {
                        openedId = id;
                    });
                } else {
                    $(id).fadeToggle(400, function() {
                        openedId = id;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

This actually checks the window width and chooses between insertAfter and just toggle. Although, this works as expected, please tell me if there is a proper way of achieving this. The above solution looks like a hack to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your click functions you can just take the `.info-content-box` and `insertAfter` the `.info-box

```js
// Code goes here

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.info-content-box').hide();

    var openedId = '';

    $('.info-box .info-header').click(function(e) {
        var id = '#' + $(this).data('name');

        if (openedId ==='') {
            $(id).insertAfter($(this).parent());
            $(id).slideToggle(400, function() {
                openedId = id;
            });
        } else {

            if (openedId == id) {
            $(id).insertAfter($(this).parent());
                $(openedId).slideToggle(400, null);
            } else {
                $(openedId).hide(10);
                $(id).fadeToggle(400, function() {
                    openedId = id;
                });
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.info-box {
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
}

.info-box .info-header {
    background-color: #3178b9;
    height: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #f5f0e7;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.info-box .info-header:hover {
    background-color: #b4a28f;
    border: 5px solid #f5f0e7;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}

.info-box .info-header .info-line {
 float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.info-box .info-header:hover .info-line {
 float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    width: 30%;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}

.info-content-box {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:50px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content1">
            <div class="info-line"></div>
            <p>hello</p>
            <div class="info-line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content2">
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content3">
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
          <div class="info-header" data-name="content4">
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="info-content-box" id="content1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content1" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-content-box" style="text-align: right" id="content2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content2" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-content-box" id="content3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content3" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-content-box" style="text-align: right" id="content4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia eum accusantium consectetur, ab esse doloremque cum, accusamus inventore illo soluta facere illum natus quam dolorum vitae, assumenda harum sit earum.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500?text=Content4" alt="" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this works as expected on responsive mode. But on desktop, it does not work well. It pushes the boxes following the clicked one below.

Answer (score 0):

use jquerys animate function

i have added docs from jquery website and and since im lazy i threw the full code example into a codepen link, hope this helps

```
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='foo'></div>
<div class='showBox'>
<img class='show'>
<img class='show'>
<img class='show'>
<img class='show'>
</div>

    body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.foo:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
/*haha ironic*/
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

.showBox {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

$(function(){
  $('.foo').on('click', function(){
    $('.showBox').animate({
      height: "toggle"
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

EDIT: also i highly recommend if you want to hide something, set the display property to none in css instead of your js code.

https://codepen.io/nicholas-rotondo/pen/bWjoBz

http://api.jquery.com/animate/